# Y-axis labels aren't showing properly on scatter plot on Python with matplotlib

Tags: python, plot, label, axis, scatter

I'm trying to plot some data using the matlib package on Python. However, when I try to plot a set of data then set the y axis limits, the labels on the y-axis do not show the full range that I'd like. In fact, it only shows values for that are written in the data.

I've tried changing the y-axis limits. I've tried plotting it with another set of data, but the labels don't seem to change. When I plot with the temp Vec that has data from 80-100, it'll show the entire axis range from 0, 100. When I try to plot the relative humidity vector, it only plots data from the range of the available data from around 0 - 40.

```
with open('April_26.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
next(readCSV) #skips the first row which is the headers

#Initialize arrays
timeVec = []
tempVec = []
relHumidityVec = []

#loop through each row
for row in readCSV: #for each row in the CSV file
    ##Storing specific data
#Note: CSV data is in strings so convert the integers if they are to be 
treated as such
    time = int(row[0]) 
    temp = int(row[2])
    relHum =row[3]

#append to array
    timeVec.append(time/1000)
    tempVec.append(temp)
    relHumidityVec.append(relHum)

#initialize plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#plt.scatter(timeVec, tempVec)
plt.scatter(timeVec, relHumidityVec, s = 4, marker = 'o', c = 'blue' , alpha = 0.4)
plt.scatter(timeVec, tempVec, s = 4, marker = 'o', c = 'red' , alpha = 0.4)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
```

I expect the plot to plot my two plots (temp vs time, relative humidity vs time) while plotting the full range for time and full range on the y-axis from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It's because from reading the .csv file, all the values are string types. My relative humidity vector was still in string type so I just had to convert to int with the code.

```
relHum = int(row[3])
```